# Jquery autocomplete validator

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have added a search dropdown menu with jquery. It works, showing `not match` message as expected when I enter not matching data. But when I select one of dropdown items and then update it by remove some characters, `not match` would not show. How could do that?

```
var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"];

var bTags = ["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "ccccccc", "ddddddddd"];


$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: aTags.concat(bTags),
  response: function(e, result) {
    if (!result.content.length) {
      console.log('No matches!');
      jQuery('#messag').html("Not match...").show();
    } else {
      jQuery('#messag').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working as expected, if you match some word from the list and then delete the last character it will still matching the word, because is and autocomplete..., as long as it includes some subtext it will be matched..

```js
var aTags = ["ask", "always", "all", "alright", "one", "foo", "blackberry", "tweet", "force9", "westerners", "sport"];

var bTags = ["aaaaaaa", "bbbbbbbb", "ccccccc", "ddddddddd"];


$("#tags").autocomplete({
  source: aTags.concat(bTags),
  response: function(e, result) {
    console.log(result);
    if (!result.content.length) {
      console.log('No matches!');
      jQuery('#messag').html("Not match...").show();
    } else {
      jQuery('#messag').hide();
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <input id="tags">
```

Comment: is it possible to doing like this site https://www.montway.com/quote ? this site has two autocomplete input field, when I want to change any text after select a drop-down field its removed the text.